# Is it required more than one virtual users to perform load test on RESTfull web services?

Tags: rest, load-testing, neoload

I have to perform load test on REST web services of 1000 concurrent users activities. I have selected NeoLoad tool for it. Is it required to have license for 1000 virtual users to simulate 1000 users or form one virtual user I can simulate 1000 users activities?

Answer (score 0):

Load testing tools (like NeoLoad) price their license based on concurrent virtual users. So, if you have a license for a single user, you can create many requests, but only one at a time. To general load of 1000 users concurrently, you'll need a 1000 users license.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate 1000 concurrent users you really need 1000 VUs as if you use only one you would be:

- having wrongly good responsectimes due to caching effect
- having wrongly negative response times due to contention on writing
- you would probably not be reproducing the production behaviour of server regarding memory usage, caching....

But note that for http restful load testing you could go for a lot of free production ready open sources like Apache JMeter, locust...

- https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right
- https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/test-rest-apis-authentication-using-jmeter/